# Choosing the ground for circuit

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, arduino-uno

Can the GND pin of the Arduino UNO be used as a ground instead of the negative terminal of a battery while using a battery as the power source? If no, do we have the liberty to choose our ground for the circuit OR DOES THE NEGATIVE TERMINAL ALWAYS HAVE TO BE THE GROUND WHEN WE USE A BATTERY AS A POWER SOURCE?

Comment: Hi, Can you edit your question and add more details / images / photos / schematic etc., to give more context to explain (a) exactly what you mean, (b) what the different options are, which you are trying to choose between, and (c) especially what you mean by "*used as a ground*"? Thanks.

Comment: By ground I mean physical ground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a floating circuit without external references you can use any node that is convenient as "ground", it is just a reference point for measuring things relative to (usually but not always a power rail is a good choice).

I hate that word (especially around beginners) because it means at least three different things in a subtly context dependent way (That can sometimes be really dangerous), far better to talk about measuring relative to a defined reference node.

Now by convention in a single supply circuit the most negative rail is usually used, but that does not have to be the case. 
For example, if you have a battery powering something with a rail splitter (very common when opamps are in play for audio for example), it may well be more convenient to (for some measurements) consider that mid rail to be 'ground', even if it is a few volts above the battery negative terminal.

Another example is the diagrams of early transistor radios, where because the PNP transistors of the day were much better then the early NPN parts, it was common practise to use the POSITIVE supply rail as ground and run all the doings at negative voltages WRT that rail.

A more digital example would be things like ECL (traditionally run from a -5.2V rail with reference being the positive 'ground'), PECL (Runs from a normal sort of supply, BUT the signals are referenced to the positive rail, not "ground"!

Note that in all cases you must ensure you stay within the parts specified voltage range, so level shifters may be required if doing something weird.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the rest of the stuff you have.

For example if you have a high-power motor, then it would be unwise to route its ground current through the tiny arduino GND pin. In this case the ground of the motor controller should be connected directly to the battery negative terminal so the motor current does not go through the arduino.

However, for low-current loads, it matters much less.

If you have an analog sensor which outputs a voltage relative to GND, and want to measure it with the arduino ADC, which also measures relative to local GND, then it makes sense to connect the sensor ground to the arduino GND.

Extra credit: read up on [common impedance coupling](https://learnemc.com/common-impedance-coupling).

Comment: "If you have an analog sensor which outputs a voltage relative to GND, and want to measure it with the arduino ADC, which also measures relative to local GND, then it makes sense to connect the sensor ground to the arduino GND." Not only "makes sense" but is quite mandatory to get correct measurements. Always think about the currents in the wire and voltage drop they cause.

Comment: @TemeV yeah I wanted to write a paragraph about [common impedance coupling](https://learnemc.com/common-impedance-coupling) but got too lazy ;)